# ElasticSearch: query for checking if exist element with specified field value

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a list of element ids (for example: [1, 23, 42, 45]) and I'm looking for the fastest way to check if in ES database elements with those ids already exist or not. In result I want to recieve response containing only ids which are present in Elasticsearch: for example [1, 42] - what means that elements with ids 1 and 42 are yet in DB.

Now I send a query for all element ids in the DB and then check if on those list are my [1, 23, 42, 45] or not. Is there any faster way ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ids` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/query-dsl-ids-query.html):

```
GET /your_index/your_type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "ids": {
      "values": [1, 23, 42, 45]
    }
  },
  "fields": []
}
```

Comment: Note 2017 Update: The post originally included "fields": [] but since then the name has changed and stored_fields is the new value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way, if what you are wanting is just a list of existing ids from the list you supply (I can't tell if that's what you're asking for or not):

```
POST /test_index/_search?search_type=count
{
    "aggs": {
        "id_terms": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "id",
                "include": [1, 23, 42, 45]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I have documents with ids `1,2,3,42`, the response is:

```
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 4,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "id_terms": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": 1,
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": 42,
               "doc_count": 1
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the code I used to test it:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/96d8d27078e74f7645eee85044b59899c57d0022